# Issues of Jenkins build scheduling on Windows: delays in the execution of scheduled builds

Tags: windows, jenkins, scheduled-tasks

My company installed Jenkins as a *Windows Service* on a VM with Windows 7 Professional. We scheduled 3 tasks for the night: one at 6.00, one at 6.10, one at 6.20. By looking at Jenkins logs, we saw that all the 3 tasks where delayed to around 7.20.

By looking at the Windows Event Viewer we discovered that the machine used to go to **sleep mode** after 30 minutes without activity (this is set in the Power Options of the Control Panel ).

Anyway, some windows scheduled task was waking up the machine (namely, some windows service for synchronizing the clock) every some time. By chance it was waking up at 7.20... As a consequence, also Jenkins was able to complete its tasks scheduled for one hour before.

**Question:** Do you know a better way to fix this other than disabling the "Put computer to sleep" option?

[image]

Comment: I'd say it's not a good idea to allow a continuous integration server to go to sleep - kind of negates the "continuous" part ;-)  This is especially so if you configure jobs to trigger on SCM changes, which could happen at any time.

Answer (score 0):

First - there is the obvious answer.  Don't let the Jenkins server go to to sleep.

But there might be reasons for it.  Personally, I have my own Jenkins server sleep during non-work hours.  To get my server to wake up at the beginning of the day, I scheduled my own task in the Windows Scheduler that would wake the computer up 10 minutes before the first scheduled Jenkins task.  The task could be anything, but the important part was flagging it to wake up the computer.

To go back to sleep at the end of the day, I have a Jenkins job that is set to trigger at the end of the day.  The Job is a Windows Shell command "%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Standby" that puts the Jenkins server back to sleep.